# Data not updating in a reactJs page component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider the following code:

App.jsx:

```
import TripDay from "./pages/TripDay";

export default () =>
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/me/trips/:tripUrlSlug/days/:tripDayNum" component={TripDay}/>
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

TripDay.jsx

```
import {getTripDay} from "../modules/TripDay/trip-day.action";

@connect((store) => store.tripDayReducer)
export default class TripDay extends Component {
   // constructor code suppressed for this question

   componentWillMount() {
     const { tripUrlSlug, tripDayNum } = this.props.match.params;
     const {dispatch} = this.props;
     dispatch(getTripDay({tripUrlSlug, tripDayNum}));
   }

   render() {
     const {tripDay, loading, dispatch} = this.props;

     const tripDayNum = parseInt(this.props.match.params.tripDayNum);
     const tripUrlSlug = this.props.match.params.trip;

     const trip = tripDay.trip;
     const nextDayLink = (tripDayNum !== trip.days.length
                          ? `/me/trips/${tripUrlSlug}/days/${tripDayNum + 1}`
                          : null);
     const prevDayLink = (tripDayNum !== 1
                          ? `/me/trips/${tripUrlSlug}/days/${tripDayNum - 1}`
                          : null);

     return <Layout>
              {prevDayLink &&
              <Link className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm pull-left" to={prevDayLink}>
                  <i className="fa fa-chevron-left mr-2" />
                  Day: {tripDayNum - 1}
              </Link>
              }

              {nextDayLink &&
              <Link className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm pull-right" to={nextDayLink}>
                  Day: {tripDayNum + 1}
                  <i className="fa fa-chevron-right ml-2" />
              </Link>
              }

              <h1 className="h4">Day-{tripDayNum}: {tripDay.title}</h1>
        </Layout>;
   }
```

As you can see, it's a simple page with 2 buttons to move between days of a trip itinerary. The route is all handled fine but the "h1" {tripDay.title} does not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Following the handy link pointed by Ben, I tried handling these lifecycle events:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const tripUrlSlug = this.props.match.params.trip;
  const tripDayNum = this.props.match.params.tripDayNum;
  const {dispatch} = this.props;
  dispatch(getTripDay({tripUrlSlug, tripDayNum}));
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    let prevTripDayNum = prevProps.match.params.tripDayNum;
    let newTripDayNum = this.props.match.params.tripDayNum;

    console.log(prevTripDayNum, newTripDayNum);

    if (newTripDayNum !== prevTripDayNum) {
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(getTripDay({tripUrlSlug, tripDayNum}));
    }
}
```

I'm seeing that the `componentDidUpdate` is not being hit at all when moving to a different day in the itinerary i.e., with different parameters between the same route.

Comment: whats the structure of `tripDay`?

Comment: `{title: "<string>"}`

Comment: While debugging, I don't see `componentWillMount` being hit for the clicks on the day links.

Comment: That's because the component isn't unmounting and remounting - you're rendering the same component with different parameters and react-router's pretty clever with this kind of thing. You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and update it there - here's a good link to [react-router's Component Lifecycle methods](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/c865bc6b331eabd853641dcc7e0224a7dce76f3b/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md)

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley I went through the very handy link you shared. I have edited my question with what I have tried. But I'm seeing that `componentDidUpdate` is not being hit at all.

Comment: My bad.. I had an empty `componentDidUpdate` declaration below. It is now working great, as mentioned in my edit. Thanks @BenKolyaMansley.